# If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for a linear operator $T(x)$ and if $g(t)$ is a polynomial, then $g(T(x)) = g(\lambda)x$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Also note that, $x \in V$, where $V$ is a vectorspace over a field $F$ and the co-efficient's of $g(t)$ are in $F$

My attempt:

I proved that $T^m(x) = \lambda^mx$ for any positive integer $m$ in an earlier question.

Using that fact we have, $$g(T(x))= a_m\lambda^mx + .... + a_2\lambda^2x + a_1\lambda^1x + a_0$$

but the constant term doesn't allow $g(T(x)) = g(\lambda)x$ unless $a_0=0$ or $x=1$ as far as I can see.

Am I missing something?

Comment: $T^0 = I$. Hence $T^0 x = 1 \cdot x$.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. You claim that $T(x)=\lambda x$ for all $x$? This is obviously not true. Or is $x$ the corresponding eigenvector?

Comment: Thank you copper.hat. $T^0$ is the identity operator So, for $g(T(x))$ gives $a_0x$ for the last term, correct?

Answer (score 1):

As written this makes no sense: you don't have a multiplication operation on vectors. Presumably what is meant is $g(T)x$ or $(g(T))(x)$, and $x$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. For that, it is easy to check the desired result. Note that by convention $T^0=I$, so the "constant" term still has an x in it (it just does not have a $T$ in it).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I thought that was the case just wasn't sure. Is this the right way to think about it: $T^0$ is the identity operator. So $g(T(x))$ gives $a_0x$ for the last term, correct?